# Upgrading all packages except Gnome

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, package-management

I would like to know if there is a specific command to upgrade my whole system except Gnome with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

In a previous post I found the following command to exclude one packet from upgrade `sudo apt-mark hold [package]`, but I don't think that this is suitable for my purpose because gdm3 has dependencies, so I think I shouldn't upgrade those too.

Is this statement right or am I wrong?

Please, provide a detailed solution. Thanks you all

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade everything except GNOME? GNOME is a core part of the system, it's a bad idea not to upgrade it, but anyway, upgrades for GNOME don't really come out so much...

Comment: I suspect last Gnome update to be the cause of black screen after few minutes from login, so I would like to try updating the system except Gnome and related packages. But if you say that's a bad idea, I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: I suggest that you start by filing a bug report on this issue on LaunchPad.